# How can I get the data values of blocks added through ModLoader?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I have installed [ModLoader](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/75440-v11-risugamis-mods-everything-updated/) and several ModLoader mods (light sensors, shelves, etc). I am also using [Zombe's modpack](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/91055-v110-zombes-modpack-26-mods-v59-upd-13jan/), and am setting up custom build sets.

What I need to know is how I can get the data values of the new items added through ModLoader, so I can add them to my custom build sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Minecraft Wiki attempts to list known mod block data values [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mod_data_values).

However, I enabled Zombe's info mod, which gives you the data value of any block being held (defaults to F12,) and the information was inconsistent with the page above. Using Zombe's info mod, I determined that the data value for the light sensor is 131, which worked when redefining my configurations.

Answer (score 0):

TooManyItems can show all blocks and their id's in game along with being able to spawn them.